# Killing Avacyn Before She Transforms During Upkeep?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Long question short: Can I kill an un-transformed [Archangel Avacyn](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bArchangel%20Avacyn%5d) during the upkeep she's due to flip, before she flips?

From how I understand it (copied by from a comment from murgatroid99):

1. A non-Angel creature dies. Archangel Avacyn's triggered ability goes on the stack.
2. Archangel Avacyn's triggered ability resolves, and creates a delayed      triggered ability.
3. At the beginning of the next upkeep, the delayed triggered ability goes on the stack.

Could I, for example, cast an instant like Lightning Axe at this point, and deal 5 damage to the currently 4/4 Avacyn? Thus preventing the transformation and the damage that is dealt on the flip?

Thanks for any help in advanced!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, this works just like you think it does. Avacyn's delayed trigger goes on the stack, you have a chance to respond and kill her. If you do, she can't transform, so the triggered ability does nothing as it resolves.